# An active access token must be used to query information about the current user - OAuthException Spring Social

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-social

I'm getting

```
OAuth Exception
    {
       "error": {
          "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
          "type": "OAuthException"
       }
    }
```

using spring social ProviderSignInController. As the controller internally takes care of retrieving the access token I'm not knowing how to debug this.

Answer (score 1):

You can download spring-source from Github [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social) and build in your environment in order to debug.